# Draw a path from a node to another path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node, tikz-path

I have a digraph and I would like to draw a path that starts, let's say in node 2 and ends at the near start of path 2->4. IT's slightly different from a loop from 1 to 1.

What I am trying to achieve:

---

[image]

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, 
        shorten > = 1pt, 
        auto,
        node distance = 3cm, 
        semithick 
    ]

    \tikzstyle{every state}=[
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm
    ]

    \node[state] (1) at (0,2) {$1$};
    \node[state] (2) at (2,4) {$2$};
    \node[state] (3) at (2,0) {$3$};
    \node[state] (4) at (6,4) {$4$};
    \node[state] (5) at (6,0) {$5$};
    \node[state] (6) at (8,2) {$6$};

    \path[->] (1) edge node  {0.8} (2);
    \path[->] (1) edge node [left] {0.75} (3);
    \path[->] (1) edge [loop above,thick] node {$A$} (2);
    \path[->] (2) edge node {0.7} (4);
    \path[->] (2) edge node [near start] {0.8} (5);
    \path[->] (2) edge node [near start] {0.58} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node [near start] {0.8} (4);
    \path[->] (3) edge node [near start] {0.62} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node [below] {0.8} (5);
    \path[->] (4) edge node {0.8} (6);
    \path[->] (5) edge node {0.7} (6);
    \path[->] (1.-20) edge [draw=blue] node {} (3.110);
    \path[->] (3.20) edge [draw=blue] node {} (4.-110);
    \path[->] (4.-20) edge [draw=blue] node {} (6.110);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to full small document. in preamble are information needed to test code .... (as used libraries etc) .

Comment: any news? or you forgot on your question?

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

for this are needed two changes in your code:

```
\path[->] (2) edge node {0.7}  coordinate[pos=0.2] (2a) (4);    % <--- changes
    \path[->] (2) edge [out=75,in=90, looseness=3] (2a);        % <--- added
```

**eddit:**
maybe you liked the following automaton looks:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, quotes}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
                       > = stealth,
               shorten > = 1pt,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small, auto=left, sloped}
                    ]
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={state, thick, minimum size = 4mm}]
\node   (1) at (0,2) {$1$};
\node   (2) at (2,4) {$2$};
\node   (3) at (2,0) {$3$};
\node   (4) at (6,4) {$4$};
\node   (5) at (6,0) {$5$};
\node   (6) at (8,2) {$6$};
    \end{scope}
\path[->]   
    (1) edge ["0.8"]                    (2)    
    (1) edge ["0.75" ']                   (3)
    (1) edge [loop above,thick,"$A$"]   (2)
    (2) edge ["0.7"]  coordinate[pos=0.2] (2a) (4)  % <--- changes
        (2) edge [out=75,in=90, looseness=2]  (2a)  % <--- added
    (2) edge [near start,"0.8"]         (5)
    (2) edge [near start,"0.58"]        (6)
    (3) edge [near start,"0.8"]         (4)
    (3) edge [near end,"0.62"]        (6)
    (3) edge ["0.8"]                    (5)
    (4) edge ["0.8"']                    (6)
    (5) edge ["0.7"]                    (6);
%
\path[draw=blue, ->] 
    (1.-20) edge    (3.110)
    (3.20)  edge    (4.-110)
    (4.-20)  to     (6.110);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

**edit:**
apparently op forgot on her/his question ... so i complete above 
code snippet to *mwe* (that can be simpler tested by anyone else interested).